# Speeding up NDSolve when solving same system for millions of initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations

For a fluid dynamics problem, I need to integrate a first-order differential equation for a fixed time for many points in space:
$$
\dot {\mathbf x} = {\mathbf f}({\mathbf x})
$$
Suppose that $\mathbf x$ is two-dimensional. Solving for one trajectory for a fixed amount of time is straightfoward with `NDSolve[]`. However, I want to compute quantities that require millions of adjacent initial conditions to be integrated for the same amount of time.

One way to do this is to use `ParallelTable[]`. However, I am curious if there is a way to put fewer calls into `NDSolve[]` by vectorizing the equations. For example, when using a fixed-step Euler integrator I could treat the entire space of N initial points as a vector of length $2 N$, and then at each timestep update the values in the entire vector. Is there a straightforward way to do this with `NDSolve[]`, and would it yield a performance benefit? If not, are there another tricks for `NDSolve[]` that may help in this use case?

Comment: Yes, vectorization is good and you should look at `ParametricNDSolve`, for get `ParallelTable` until you have a very efficient `NDSolve` call. But since you do not provide any code, nothing definite can be said.

Comment: For a simple fixed step integration you might get better performance if you forgo `NDSolve` and implement it yourself.

Comment: @user21 Thank you for the suggestion, I did not know about ParametricNDSolve. I've tried it, and based just on looking at the timing, it looks like ParametricFunction objects just delay evaluation of all the integrals until a value of the ParametricFunction is requested for specific parameter values, and so I get similar timing to running NDSolve within a Table. $f(x)$ is complicated (but analytic) expression in terms of polynomials and common functions. I have tried compiling it as well. How else would parallelization be accomplished using NDSolve?